# Want your work published at Lifehacker & Ars Technica? Stack Exchange needs photos for syndication

Tags: discussion, contest, crowdhacker

As maybe you've noticed, we regularly send out some of (y)our content to [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/crowdhacker/) and [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/author/stack-exchange/).

But we always find ourselves asking this question: What to do about the header photo!?

Perhaps the answer lies before our eyes, here, at the photo site.

**A Proposal:**

Would you be interested in hosting a weekly or semi-weekly photo contest to determine what images get published along with the Q&A?

The contest will be topic-based around a number of Q&As pre-approved by the publisher. A winner for each Q&A will be determined by vote and his or her photo will be properly credited at the site where it is published.

Think this might work? Does it interest you? Can you think of any ways to improve the format of this contest so that it works flawlessly and produces high-quality images?

Look forward to reading your input!

Answer (score 8):

Love it.

Want to do it.

I think it sounds like a good idea.

---

We should be able to run it similar the Picture of the Week contest, but we will need plenty of 'heads up' time before hand.  Members may have to create an image for it, so the contest would need sufficient time to generate the pictures.

Comment: I agree with rfusca, should be easy to run it just like the PotW contest. At the moment, that works very well, and runs like clockwork.

Comment: Sam and I have talked about this in person, and I think it's a great idea. There are a lot of talented people on here, and it's a great way for users to gain exposure for their work as well as gaining exposure for the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: I would agree, but it may need a little more lead time than a week if the subject is a little esoteric like some the coding ones can be...

Comment: JoanneC: I agree.  These may have to be composed, new images because of the esoteric nature - so a couple weeks may be needed.